# Localize TemplateId InputParameter value in Azure B2C custom policy with SendGrid custom email verification

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, sendgrid, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I would like to pass a different value of my SendGrid templateid in B2C custom policy, depending on user language. So i was trying to do that via custom policy Localization but it doesnt work for me.
Here's how my ClaimsTransformation node looks like:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GenerateEmailRequestBody" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.to.0.email" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="subject" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.subject" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otp" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.otp" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.email" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="message" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.message" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="codeIntro" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.codeIntro" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signature" TransformationClaimType="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.signature" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="template_id" DataType="string" Value="SendGridTemplateId" />
      <InputParameter Id="from.email" DataType="string" Value="myemail@blabla.com" />
      <InputParameter Id="personalizations.0.dynamic_template_data.subject" DataType="string" Value="Contoso account email verification code"/>
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailRequestBody" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
```

and here's Localization node:

```
  <LocalizedResources Id="api.custom-email.en">
    <LocalizedStrings>        
      <LocalizedString ElementType="FormatLocalizedStringTransformationClaimType" StringId="SendGridTemplateId">d-mytemplateidhere...</LocalizedString>
```

I tried to do that according to this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization#formatlocalizedstringtransformationclaimtype

But Im getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have exactly the same problem

Comment: I passed current user locale using referenced JS files, which made calls to my API

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you are sending "SendGridTemplateId" as it's hardcoded.

You need to make it an InputClaim.

Maybe you could use [claims resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview) to get the language and then claims transformations to set the correct ID.